# DIVIDIR UN SOLO VALOR DE UNA SUMA EN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[[image: ejemplo en excel 1]

he intentado esto

```
select CASE WHEN ZONE_REPRESENTANT iN  ('DIRECTION COMMERCIALE','RHONE ALPES SUD', 'SUD & CORSE', 'MARQUAGE TEXTILE','GRAND EST', 'RHONE ALPES NORD') THEN 'Zone 1'
        WHEN ZONE_REPRESENTANT IN ('DéCORATION', 'SOLUTION INDUSTRIELLE', 'AUTOMOTIVE', 'ILE DE FRANCE EST')THEN 'Zone 2' 
        END, 
        
        SUM(meas_budget_ca_eur) from dwh.BUDGET.FACT_BUDGET_FOR_R2D2 inner join dwh.dim.DIM_REPRESENTANT ON FACT_BUDGET_FOR_R2D2.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID = DIM_REPRESENTANT.DIM_REPRESENTANT_ID

        WHERE FACT_BUDGET_ID LIKE 'HEXIS FRA/CAD2%' AND DIM_CALENDAR_BUDGET_ID LIKE '2022%'
              AND ZONE_REPRESENTANT IN ('DéCORATION', 'SOLUTION INDUSTRIELLE', 'AUTOMOTIVE', 'ILE DE FRANCE EST','DIRECTION COMMERCIALE','RHONE ALPES SUD', 'SUD & CORSE', 'MARQUAGE TEXTILE','GRAND EST', 'RHONE ALPES NORD')

group by CASE WHEN ZONE_REPRESENTANT iN  ('DIRECTION COMMERCIALE','RHONE ALPES SUD', 'SUD & CORSE', 'MARQUAGE TEXTILE','GRAND EST', 'RHONE ALPES NORD') THEN 'Zone 1'
         WHEN ZONE_REPRESENTANT IN ('DéCORATION', 'SOLUTION INDUSTRIELLE', 'AUTOMOTIVE', 'ILE DE FRANCE EST') THEN 'Zone 2' END
```

sin embargo aqui solo divido en dos CASE uno 'CHELAL' Y el otro PFESENCIEUX, debo tomar solo el valor de MARQUEAGE Y dividirlo en dos, no se como afectuarlo. Agradezco cualquier asesoria

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer, se supone que es condicionar la suma. Para que cuando sea una expresión verdadera, solo sume la mitad y sino completa. SUM(case when expr then valor else valor/2 end)

Comment: No, Mira cada case contiene loas valores de cierta celda de la misma columna, los cuales se deben sumar sin embargo una sola celda se debe dividir por dos una unica celda, nunca va a sumar completa

Comment: Indepndientemente de lo que pides, la consulta no se parece en nada a lo que solicitas. Eso a priori parece un pivot (ya sea dinámico o estático). Crea un escenario real, con datos, bien sea mediante scripts o un sql fiddle. [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que requieres, necesitas indicar como dividir cada valor que requieras. Esto se puede hacer agregando una tabla. En este caso, dejo una forma de hacerlo creando una tabla virtual. Así también evitas estar repitiendo códigos. Recuerda que el uno es el elemento neutro de la división.

Nota: Es probable que los prefijos estén mal, pero traté de adivinar a que tabla pertenecía cada columna.

```
SELECT zr.zone, 
       SUM( b.meas_budget_ca_eur / zr.factor)
FROM       dwh.BUDGET.FACT_BUDGET_FOR_R2D2 b
INNER JOIN dwh.dim.DIM_REPRESENTANT        r ON b.dim_representant_id = r.dim_representant_id
INNER JOIN (VALUES( 'DéCORATION'            , 'Zone 2', 1.),
                  ( 'SOLUTION INDUSTRIELLE' , 'Zone 2', 1.),
                  ( 'AUTOMOTIVE'            , 'Zone 2', 1.),
                  ( 'ILE DE FRANCE EST'     , 'Zone 2', 1.),
                  ( 'DIRECTION COMMERCIALE' , 'Zone 1', 1.),
                  ( 'RHONE ALPES SUD'       , 'Zone 1', 1.),
                  ( 'SUD & CORSE'           , 'Zone 1', 1.),
                  ( 'MARQUAGE TEXTILE'      , 'Zone 1', 2.),
                  ( 'GRAND EST'             , 'Zone 1', 1.),
                  ( 'RHONE ALPES NORD'      , 'Zone 1', 1.)) zr(zone_representant, zone, factor) on r.zone_representant = zr.zone_representant

WHERE b.fact_budget_id LIKE 'HEXIS FRA/CAD2%' 
AND b.dim_calendar_budget_id LIKE '2022%'
GROUP BY zr.zone;
```